# How can I make a PDF of the source of pdftex?

Tags: tex-core, web

I got the files tex.web and pdftex.web from the texlive svn repo.  I ran

```
weave tex.web
pdftex tex.tex
```

which produced a file `tex.pdf` with a nicely typeset, cross-referenced listing of the WEB source of TeX.

However, if I do the same process pdftex.web, the resulting file `pdftex.pdf` only contains the pages corresponding to the index.

Is there some other combination of commands I need to run, or do I need to edit part of pdftex.web?  I tried weaving in the supplied `.ch` files, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I was looking for pdftex.web, and it turns out it can be browsed online directly through the texlive SVN at this link: https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/pdftexdir/pdftex.web?view=co

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply change the line

```
\let\maybe=\iffalse % print only changed modules
```

to

```
\let\maybe=\iftrue
```

in `pdftex.web`.

Comment: I forgot to add that you may also want to change `\input webmac` to `\input pdfwebmac` at the top of the weaved `pdftex.tex` to enable hyperlinks, which makes for more pleasant reading.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike `tex.web` which was from the beginning intended by Knuth for producing both a documented book of the source code listing ([Computers & Typesetting](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde.html#abcde) Volume B, *TeX: The Program*) and the actual program of TeX, the file `pdftex.web` is simply a changed `tex.web` that was done with the primary goal of producing a working and usable pdfTeX program, with no intention (AFAIK) of it being readable as a standalone book (beyond whatever is needed for the program to be maintainable). So producing a typeset listing of the `pdftex` source is somewhat less meaningful: the result won't be as coherent as that for `tex` (which you can read with [`texdoc tex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf), though that misses the useful mini-indexes and “How to read a WEB” that the printed book has).

Nevertheless, if you want to typeset the source code of pdftex, just to see it once for yourself, this is what I had to do just now (as of 2017 October):

1. Get the latest `pdftex.web` (say from [here](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/web2c/pdftexdir/pdftex.web?view=co)).
2. Run `weave` as `weave pdftex.web`. It produces a `pdftex.tex` file.
3. Change `\ifffalse` to `\iftrue` in `pdftex.tex` where it says:

   ```
   \let\maybe=\iffalse % print only changed modules
   ```
4. Optional: Change `\input webmac` at the top of the file to `\input pdfwebmac`, to get hyperlinks for section (module) references.
5. Run `pdftex` on the file: `pdftex pdftex.tex`. It will produce a typeset `pdftex.pdf`.

Note that until October 2017, two additional changes (in the first revision of this answer) were needed. This suggests that no one else uses it this way (at least among the pdfTeX developers), or they would have fixed it.

Somewhat related: Taco Hoekwater's article [*LuaTeX says goodbye to Pascal*](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96hoekwater-pascal.pdf) from EuroTeX 2009, describing some awkwardness they encountered as a team working together on a WEB document, and their conversion to C files. Some of the issues may apply to pdfTeX too (though they still use web): What worked for Knuth as a single programmer, keeping the whole program in his head, writing the entirety of it on paper, and typing it in when finished, with always the intention of making it a book and stopping development once he was done, may not make as much sense for a team of present-day programmers who are trying to develop to changing requirements and incorporate new ideas as they go along—and definitely aren't in the habit of writing programs with pencil and paper.

Comment: I have sent a patch with (2) and (4) above, to the pdftex developers: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2017-August/thread.html Will edit this answer when that patch is applied and reflected on the SVN sources.

Comment: The patch has been applied: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2017-October/ (I have edited the above answer, so the previous comment above applies only to the first revision of the answer.)

Comment: As of 2017-Nov-01, the patch has also been [applied](https://tug.org/svn/pdftex/branches/stable/source/src/texk/web2c/pdftexdir/pdftex.web?r1=778&r2=780) in the `pdftex` (not just TeX Live) repository. So the hard-to-weave version of `pdftex.web` (2011–2017) should no longer be around in any up-to-date repository.